# Echo from MySQL database with spaces and line breaks?

Tags: php, mysql

I noticed that when I submit text to my MySQL form in VARCHAR it does store line breaks. (Since they show in PHPMyAdmin).  However when I echo column Text, I get everything in a single line.

How can I echo values retaining line breaks?

Comment: it does store line breaks, but html interpreters (browsers) do not do anything with them, you need the html equivalent of <br>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php