# PHP wont show new line

Tags: php, mysql, process

i have a little problem with the text to be readed from my database.
After the user has confirmed their new post, it saves in the database like this ( like i want it to do).

[image]

but in the webpage, it will ignore these lines, and just echo out everything on the same line.

[image]

Here is a bit my source code:

```
$objekttekst=str_replace("\\r\\n", "<br>", $obj->innhold);

        $objekttittel=$obj->tittel;
?>
<h2><?=$objekttittel?></h2>

<p><?=$objekttekst?></p>
```

could someone help me out? thanks

Comment: `"\\r\\n"` is replacing literally `\r\n` to `<br>`, not what `\r\n` represent because you are escaping the escape character.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9457835/67332

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)** function.

```php
$objekttekst = nl2br($obj->innhold);
```

Answer (score 1):

The input textarea is pre-formatted, which means that it will show any newlines that the user enters. However, HTML rendered (web browser) does not display any newlines from the input, unless newlines are explicitly inserted with tags such as `<BR>`.

You have several options here. For sure these three are not your only options, but they are the ones I have personally been using most often.

**Form textarea with pre-formatted text**

If you want to display the data (*objekttekst*) in a similar textarea where the input was given, you could do:

```
<h2><?=$objekttittel?></h2>
<p><textarea><?=$objekttekst?></textarea></p>
```

This would suit you best in a situation where the user needs a possibility to edit the entry.

**Preformatting**

If you want to display the text as it is, you can always surround it with `<PRE>...</PRE>`. That will show any newlines, indentations etc. Note that this will make the output use a fixed-width font such as *Courier New*.

**Convert newlines to `<BR>` tags**

Use function `nl2br()` as already mentioned in another answer. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php for more information.

**Additional note...**

You might want to look into *regular expressions*, as in many cases you might want to do also some other modifications to your data before showing it in the HTML page. `nl2br()` will take care of newlines, but for other and more complex modifications you should learn regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your string with `<pre>` tag instead of replacing `\n` with `<br>`

Example:

```
  <?php
    $objekttekst=$obj->innhold
    $objekttittel=$obj->tittel;
  ?>
  <h2><?=$objekttittel?></h2>
  <p><pre><?=$objekttekst?></pre></p>
```